# Ununderstandable Pandas groupby results

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Coming from R and been working with the tidyverse mostly, I wonder how does pandas groupby and aggregations work. I have this code and the results are heartbreaking to me.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZeccaLehn/4e06d2575eb9589dbe8c365d61cb056c/raw/64f1660f38ef523b2a1a13be77b002b98665cdfe/mtcars.csv')
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'brand'}, inplace=True)
```

Now I would like to calculate the average displacement (disp) by cylinders, like that:

```
df['avg_disp'] = df.groupby('cyl').disp.mean()
```

Which results in something like:

```
    cyl disp    avg_disp
31  4   121.0   NaN
2   4   108.0   NaN
27  4   95.1    NaN
26  4   120.3   NaN
25  4   79.0    NaN
20  4   120.1   NaN
7   4   146.7   NaN
8   4   140.8   353.100000
19  4   71.1    NaN
18  4   75.7    NaN
17  4   78.7    NaN
29  6   145.0   NaN
0   6   160.0   NaN
1   6   160.0   NaN
3   6   258.0   NaN
10  6   167.6   NaN
9   6   167.6   NaN
5   6   225.0   NaN
13  8   275.8   NaN
28  8   351.0   NaN
4   8   360.0   105.136364
24  8   400.0   NaN
23  8   350.0   NaN
22  8   304.0   NaN
21  8   318.0   NaN
6   8   360.0   183.314286
11  8   275.8   NaN
16  8   440.0   NaN
30  8   301.0   NaN
14  8   472.0   NaN
12  8   275.8   NaN
15  8   460.0   NaN
```

After searching for a while, I discovered the `transform` function which leads to the correct value for `avg_disp` by assigning the mean value to each row according to the grouping `cyl` var.
My point is... why can't it be done easily with the `mean` function instead of using `.transform('mean')` on the grouped data frame?

Comment: `df.groupby('cyl').disp.mean()` returns a new dataframe which just has one row per grouped result. When you assign that to a column in the original dataframe, it doesn't automatically spread to all rows in each group.

Comment: So, it needs to be merged with the original data frame in such case?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the results back to the ungrouped dataframe you could use [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

> ... and return a DataFrame **having the same indexes as the original object** filled with the transformed values.

```
df['avg_disp'] = df.groupby('cyl').disp.transform('mean')
```